# Attach tooltips on elements inside bootstrap buttons

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to apply Twitter Bootstrap tooltips on elements inside a Twitter Bootstrap button. For some reason, those tooltips never triggers (never show).

Markup:

```
<button title="Reset Pricing" type="button"
    class="btn btn-mini myButton"
    data-placement='bottom'>
    <i class="icon-refresh" title="Can't touch this?" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body"></i>
</button>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.icon-refresh').tooltip();
});
```

Example jsfiddle: [Trying with glyphicon](http://jsfiddle.net/JaPYg/8/)

This applies to all browsers I've tested (Firefox, IE, Chrome on Windows 7). Preferably, I want it to work on all three.

**Update #1**: According to comments, it's showing outside jsfiddle display frame. However, still not getting it to work with Firefox, but Chrome and IE works.

**Update #2**: According to person behind accepted answer, there is a bug in bootstrap tooltip (2.3.2) that causes the problem. However, using an anchor tag instead of a button one, problem is solved.

Comment: I dont get it, seem to be working for me in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is working but you don't see it because is trying to show above the button. try adding `data-placement="right"`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JaPYg/7/)

Comment: You're right, your update works with IE, however, Firefox doesn't still show it for me. Seems like I need a Firefox workaround?

Comment: @RonnieKilsbo: it seems to be a bug on bootstrap tooltip. Is it the same for you using an anchor tag instead of button? That works for me on firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/JaPYg/9/

Comment: Nope, using an anchor tag works, thank you. I guess I'll have to live with this in 2.3.2, or upgrade (if it is working in 3.x). Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is an issue again in Bootstrap 3.3.4 for nested tooltips in button elements, in both Firefox and IE.  Using an anchor tag works.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JaPYg/6/

```
<i class="icon-refresh" title="Can't touch this?" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body"></i>
```

just changed so its shows at bottom instead of default top.

Are you sure you hover the icon and not just the button? And are you sure nothing is blocking the tooltip (ie. some div or whatever)?

Comment: Noted, as I commented on the other solution, actually works, but not on Firefox for some reason.